# Why am I getting error 0x80070585 when trying to run a PHP application on IIS 7?

Tags: php, iis-7, fastcgi

I'm running IIS 7 on Windows 7.

I've installed PHP v5.3 through WebMatrix, set up a website for my PHP app in IIS, and enabled read/write access for 'Everyone', for the directory.

When I browse to the application, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
<handler> scriptProcessor could not be found in <fastCGI> application configuration
Error Code  0x80070585
```

Here's what I tried:

- Ensured that CGI is installed (Windows Features --> Internet Information Services --> World Wide Web Services --> Application Development Features --> CGI; it was already ticked.)
- Commented out all of extensions under the '[ExtensionList]' section in 'php.ini'.
- Noticed some discussion online about [editing a file called 'fcgiext.ini'](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=206306.0). Did a file-search on my hard drive for this file; 0 results.
- Noticed [this discussion](http://forums.iis.net/t/1146415.aspx), advising that whatever is in the scriptProcessor attribute of the handlers section should also be in the fastCgi section. But I already have a file called 'Web.roleconfig' in my PHP application path, which already has a fastCgi section:

  ```
  <fastCgi>
    <application fullPath="%RoleRoot%\approot\Php\php-cgi.exe" arguments="-c %RoleRoot%\approot\Php\php.ini" />
  </fastCgi>
  ```

Sorry if this is all a bit incoherent. I'm not a PHP expert, and I'm not sure where to begin to solve this problem.

At the least, any hints as to whether this is an IIS or PHP or FastCgi issue would be a great help.

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple site on IIS Express (which ships with WebMatrix)? Make sure you go to Site Settings and selected "Enable PHP". Create a simple PHP page and test that you can at least get something simple to work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try using PHP Manager to see if PHP is configured correctly for IIS.

Install PHP Manager from here, http://phpmanager.codeplex.com/

Then run it within IIS (appears as a module in IIS Mgr) to see if PHP is registered. If it isn't, click Register New version, navigate to php-cgi.exe and select it. Then click on Check PHPInfo() to ensure it's running.

Hope that helps.
Mark

Comment: It appears that I already have 'PHP Manager' installed. I ran it from within IIS. It displayed the message: 'PHP is not enabled. Register new PHP version to enable PHP via FastCGI.' So I clicked 'Register new PHP version', and was presented with a dialog where I could select the location of the executable. After I selected: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe', it gave me an error: 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object'. Not sure what this means, but I'm doing research to find out.

Comment: Never mind, I installed a new instance of PHP using WampServer, and pointed it to that instance's php-cgi.exe, and now it works.

Comment: It would be useful to use PHP Manager only if this server is newly built. If IIS configuration has already been modified after many trials, this tool won't help restore it to a healthy state, and manual editing is still required.

Comment: Also the provided solution by Php manager does not build for me at this time:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The command "CALL "%VS110COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat" > NULL
sn –Vr Web.Management.PHP.dll
gacutil.exe /if "C:\Users\sariaee\Downloads\phpmanager\sourceCode\sourceCode\trunk\bin\Debug\Web.Management.PHP.dll"" exited with code 9009. PHPManager

Comment: @OverMars binaries with installers can be found in https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases You shouldn't attempt to build the source code, especially the archived old versions from CodePlex.

Answer (score 1):

All solutions proposed above are based on tools. The underlying IIS mechanism for FastCGI support was not mentioned in details, but is the key to get things right.

1. PHP binaries for Windows must be extracted somewhere and you need to get its php.ini ready.
2. Add a module mapping in Handler Mapping section of IIS Manager (or equivalently in applicationHost.config file) at server or site level.
3. Make sure at server level's FastCGI Settings section of IIS Manager the php-cgi.exe is registered (though at previous step IIS Manager should ask if you want it to help add this entry automatically).

This IIS.net article lists more info, but it failed to mention the last step,

https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php#13

while this PHP page reveals almost everything with screenshots,

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

If you get 500.0 and 0x80070585, it is very likely that the last two steps are not completed, and you need to go back to IIS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the (Fast)CGI applications's arguments in the handler definition.

Unfortunately, this is *not* described in the [add handler documentation](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers/add), but just appears in sample documentation ([1](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis), [2](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/fastcgi/application)) about setting up PHP with IIS:

> To create these mappings, the settings in the fullPath and arguments attributes for an  element must be added to the scriptProcessor attribute in the  mapping for the FastCGI process and separated by the pipe "|" character.

So in your particular case the `scriptProcessor` within the handler definition would need to be set to:

```
<handlers>
  ...
  <add ... scriptProcessor="%RoleRoot%\approot\Php\php-cgi.exe|-c %RoleRoot%\approot\Php\php.ini" />
  ...
```

(Haven't checked if the env vars don't cause a mapping issue, though.)